# Unknown application error

Tags: c++, linux, embedded, arm

So I`m writing an application for an embeded system (Linux on ARM) and everything works fine, until I decide to add one more class at the start of a main function. It looks like this (can not post the actual code here):

```
int main ()
{
   Someclass class1;
   ....
}
```

And after that application just return code 1 (generic error) right from the start. If I remove it - everything is fine again. To me it looks like I ran out of stack space - but in that case system should throw a SIGSEV or SIGSTKFLT. But there was nothing just error code 1. I tried to get stderr like that:

```
./app 2> error.log
```

But there was also nothing.

Tried to debug using remote gdb:

Client:

Cannot access memory at address 0x3030204

Cannot access memory at address 0x3030200

Server:

Remote debugging from host xxxxxx

readchar: Got EOF

Remote side has terminated connection.

**Details:**

I`m wirting on C++11 (TR1) (project-specific), compile with GCC 4.4.6 (also project-specific), debug with GDB 7.4

**Solved**
Big thanks to everyone who responded, I have managed to solve this, and it was my fault - I did not initialized device`s libraries correctly before calling a wrapper class (later they were initialized and thus it worked). Thank you all again.

Comment: Details about your classes may help. is you system c++ enabled?

Comment: I don`t quite understand you. If you are talking about standard C++ libraries - yes, they are there.

Comment: can you use `ldd` on the executable? are all dependencies satisfied?

Comment: GCC 4.4 is not really C++11 compliant. Upgrade to GCC 4.9

Comment: No, I have no ldd on that system, but I`m using that class later in code and it works fine, so I assume that dependencies are fine.


_GCC 4.4 is not really C++11 compliant. Upgrade to GCC 4.9_
I can`t - as I said - it is project specific.


_Details about your classes may help_
Added class is simply a wrapper class around native class from device`s library.

Comment: GDB will not debug program start-up.  Things like static constructors that maybe brought in by linking that class can cause this issue.  I think there is an option, but typing `b start`, before `run` will probably put a break point on the startup.  You can use `readelf` to get the startup routine name/location.  The class constructor may access something that is not setup at that point, but is later on.  You can test stack by using `static` can't you?

Comment: @artlessnoise yes, I`ll do it and post the results.

Comment: See: [Debugging the C runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976433/debugging-the-c-runtime) and [DBP-consultings Linux start-up](http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/debugging/linuxProgramStartup.html) for instance.  The *DBP* link gives some C++ specifics; these may vary with C++ versions (fini/ini tables,etc).

Comment: Occam's Razor suggests that it is the code in the constructor of `SomeClass` that is failing.  If you cannot post the code you are probably wasting your time posting at all.  The question has little value on SO as a repository of solutions to problems. I'd say a better question to ask would be on how to get your remote debug solution to work - then you can use that to solve this specific issue and many other issues you are bound to encounter.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious place to look would be in the class' constructor which is being called on invocation of main.